# float left div containers center

Tags: html, css, center

how do I center the div elements? They only float left next to each other, but don't center.

The div elements all contain a fixed width image, under the picture comes a variable text.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div style="max-width:900px;margin: 0 auto;">
<div style="width:100%;">


<div style="float:left;"><img src="img" width="250" height="150" ><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
<div style="float:left;"><img src="img" width="250" height="150" ><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
<div style="float:left;"><img src="img" width="250" height="150" ><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
<div style="float:left;"><img src="img" width="250" height="150" ><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
<div style="float:left;"><img src="img" width="250" height="150" ><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
<div style="float:left;"><img src="img" width="250" height="150" ><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
<div style="float:left;"><img src="img" width="250" height="150" ><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>

</div>
</div>

</div>


#wrapper{

    margin: 0 auto;
        width: 900px;
    max-width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Thank you.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the floats and use `display: flex; justify-content: center; flex-wrap: wrap;` on the parent... and you don't need the 2 inner divs wrapping the cells.

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
  <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
  <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
  <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
  <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
  <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
  <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
  <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
  <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>

</div>
```

Comment: @MarcoVeLi awesome, no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the floats, use `display: inline-block;` and apply `text-align:center` to their container:

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 900px;
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

div>div>div {
  display: inline-block;
}

div>div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div style="max-width:900px;margin: 0 auto;">
    <div style="width:100%;">


      <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
      <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
      <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
      <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
      <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
      <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>
      <div><img src="img" width="250" height="150"><br>This text goes under the Picture.</div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

P.S.: If you don't like the little spaces between the DIVs, you can move every closing DIV (`</div>`) to the next line, directly in front of the next opening `<div>`. This helps to avoid the white-space caused by the line breaks in the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a div with fixed width, you can simply set the position to absolute, left to 50% and margin to -450px (half of the width)

here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmw1m64d/)

```
position:absolute;  
left:50%;
margin:0 -450px;
```